# Hanuman and the highest state of Sri Rama bhakti

Tags: ramayana, rama, hanuman, bhakti

On learning about the  whereabouts of Goddess Sita  from Jatayu’s brother Sampati, the brave Hanuman crossed the endless seas and proceeded to Lanka.
He found Goddess Sita in Ashoka Vatika and assured her that God Sri Rama would  attack Lanka soon ,to  free her from Ravana’s captivity.

On completion of his meeting with  Goddess Sita,  Hanuman took a decision to implement the strategy of "open" assault. And accordingly, started destroying the royal garden of Ravana.

> यो ब्राह्मम् अस्त्रम् वेदान् च वेद वेदविदाम् वरः |
>
> स त्वाम् दाशरथी रामो देवि कौशलम् अब्रवीत् || ५-३४-३
>
> O Divine Lady! Rama the son of Dasaratha, who is excellent among the knowers of Veda and who knows Brahma's missile (a mythical weapon which deals infallible destruction) and Vedas the sacred knowledge, enquired about your welfare."
>
> अल्प शेषम् इदम् कार्यम् दृष्टा इयम् असित ईक्षणा |
>
> त्रीन् उपायान् अतिक्रम्य चतुर्थ इह दृश्यते || ५-४१-२
>
> I have seen this black-eyed Seetha. There is only a little that remains to be done by me. Abandoning the three strategies for success{viz, sowing dissension, negotiation and bribery},I have to implement here the fourth strategy viz. open assault."
>
> ततः तद्त् हनुमान् वीरो बभन्ज प्रमदा वनम् |
>
> मत्त द्विज समाघुष्टम् नाना द्रुम लता युतम् || ५-४१-१५
>
> Then, the valiant Hanuma laid waste the royal garden attached to the gynaecium resonant with cries of birds in heat and endowed with various kinds of trees and creepers.

Hanuman was subsequently  taken as prisoner by Indrajit, the son of Ravana, and  taken to the court of Ravana.

> अवध्योऽयमिति ज्ञात्वा तमस्त्रेणास्त्रतत्त्ववित् |
>
> निजग्राह महाबाहुर्मारुतात्मजमिन्द्रजित् || ५-४८-३७
>
> Indrajit, who knows the true nature of missiles, feeling certain that he was incapable of being killed, bound that Hanuma, the son of wind-god, by that missile presided over by Brahma the Creator.

And during the meeting of Hanuman with Ravana in his Court,Ravana ordered that Hanuman’s tail  be set on fire as a punishment.

> आज्ञापयत् राक्षस इन्द्रः पुरम् सर्वम् सचत्वरम् |
>
> लान्गूलेन प्रदीप्तेन रक्षोभिः परिणीयताम् || ५-५३-५
>
> Ravana ordered that let the monkey be carried around with his burning tail by the demons in the entire city around its cross-roads.

Hanuman, being the greatest devotee of God Sri Rama,was only focussed on chanting the name of God Sri Rama, despite his tail being set on fire.

> यदिभर्तुर्हतार्थाय चरन्तम् भर्तृशासनात् || ५-५३-१२
>
> बध्नन्त्येते दुरात्मनो न तु मे निष्कृतिः कृता |
>
> If these evil-minded demons fasten me who is acting for the good of Sri Rama my lord, because of the command by their lord, no rebuff has been done to me

The question is : **Which specific attributes of a great devotee are  highlighted in this exemplary  devotional state of Hanuman, mentioned above**?
Which text on Bhakti Yoga can amplify these qualities?

Comment: माता रामो मत्पिता रामचन्द्रः ।
स्वामी रामो मत्सखा रामचन्द्रः ॥
सर्वस्वं मे रामचन्द्रो दयालु ।
नान्यं जाने नैव जाने न जाने ॥

Comment: Meaning:
1: Rama is my Mother and Rama (Ramachandra) is my Father,
2: Rama is my Lord and Rama (Ramachandra) is my Friend,
3: Rama is my All in All, O the Compassionate Rama (Ramachandra) is my All in All,
4: I do not know any other; I do not know any other; Indeed I do not know any other.

Comment: The highest state of bhakti of Lord Hanuman was when he showed Lord Rama and Mother Sita in his chest.

Comment: Nobody even dare to do that in all universe but Lord Hanuman.

Comment: What's up Uday Krishna? You are not active at all these days.

Comment: The projection of Sri Hanuman as the devotee of Sri Raama is not from Valmiki Ramayana.(https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/sundara/sarga53/sundara_53_frame.htm). It was a later day development in Bhagavata Purana and Vishnu Purana.  In Ramayana Sri Hanuman was portrayed more as a Jnani, a scholar, person endowed with supernatural powers.@Uday Krishna

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the Srimad-Bhagavata and the Vishnu Purana are mentioned the nine forms of Bhakti, which are given as under :-

(1) Sravana -hearing of God's Lilas and stories.

(2) Kirtana- singing of God’s glories.

(3) Smarana -remembrance of God’s name and presence.

(4) Padasevana- service of God’s feet.

(5) Archana- worship of God.

(6) Vandana- prostration to Lord.

(7) Dasya -cultivating the Bhava of a servant with God.

(8) Sakhya -cultivation of the friend-Bhava.

(9) Atmanivedana-complete surrender of the self to God.

Dasya Bhakti is the love of God through servant-sentiments. To serve God and carry out his wishes, realizing his virtues, nature, mystery and glory, considering oneself as a servant of God, the Supreme Master, is Dasya Bhakti.

**Hanuman’s** devotion to his master Lord Sri Rama{God Vishnu} , in the Ramayana , is the **perfect** state of **Dasya Bhakti**. Out of the nine forms of Bhakti, mentioned above, **Hanuman** had achieved the level of **perfection** in the **Dasya Bhakti** form.

A true devotee is the one who asks for **nothing** and **serves** God out of intense **love for God**, and that was **Hanuman**.

As given in Srimad Bhagavatham 7.5.23/24

> Hearing and chanting about the transcendental holy name, form, qualities, paraphernalia and pastimes of Lord Viṣṇu, remembering them, serving the lotus feet of the Lord, offering the Lord respectful worship with sixteen types of paraphernalia, offering prayers to the Lord, **becoming His servant**, considering the Lord one’s best friend, and surrendering everything unto Him (in other words, serving Him with the body, mind and words) - these nine processes are accepted as **pure devotional service**. One who has dedicated his life to the service of Kṛṣṇa through these nine methods should be understood to be the most learned person, for he has acquired complete knowledge.

QNS-Which specific attributes of a great devotee are highlighted in this exemplary devotional state of Hanuman, mentioned above?

**The answer** to this question, can be found in Hanuman's own words, which is described in a book named **Hanumat Vibhuti**. 
When Sri Rama asks Hanuman to describe their relationship,

Hanuman responds:

> deha bhudhaya dasoham, jiva bhudhaya tvamansha; atma bhudhaya tvamevaham, iti me nisicat mati
>
> From the standpoint of the physical body, I am Your servant. From the standpoint of Jeeva (soul), I am part of You. From the standpoint of Atman, You and I are one and the same. This is my confirmed opinion.

So, a **true devotee** who strives harder, in the path of **devotion** to God,attains a **similar state**, as described in the foregoing paragraph.

A sanskrit sloka about Hanuman's bhakti,given at comments @ Parth Trivedi, is as under.

> माता रामो मत्पिता रामचन्द्रः । स्वामी रामो मत्सखा रामचन्द्रः ॥
>
> सर्वस्वं मे रामचन्द्रो दयालु । नान्यं जाने नैव जाने न जाने ॥
>
> Meaning: 1: Rama is my Mother and Rama (Ramachandra) is my Father, 2: Rama is my Lord and Rama (Ramachandra) is my Friend, 3: Rama is my All in All, O the Compassionate Rama (Ramachandra) is my All in All, 4: I do not know any other; I do not know any other; Indeed I do not know any other.

There are many authentic texts on Bhakti Yoga. Link for text on Bhakti Yoga, is attached herewith. For an advanced text on Bhakti Yoga, Chapter 12: Bhakti Yoga or the Yoga of Devotion-of the Bhagavad Gita may be referred.

> अद्वेष्टा सर्वभूतानां मैत्र: करुण एव च |
>   निर्ममो निरहङ्कार: समदु:खसुख: क्षमी || 13||
>
> सन्तुष्ट: सततं योगी यतात्मा दृढनिश्चय: |
>   मय्यर्पितमनोबुद्धिर्यो मद्भक्त: स मे प्रिय: || 14||
>
> BG 12.13–12.14:
>   Those devotees are very dear to me who are free from malice toward all living beings, who are friendly, and compassionate. They are free from attachment to possessions and egotism, equipoised in happiness and distress, and ever-forgiving. They are ever-contented, steadily united with me in devotion, self-controlled, firm in conviction, and dedicated to me in mind and intellect.

Reference links :- (1)http://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/vivekananda/master_index.htm

{2}http://chinmayapublications.com/catalog.pdf

(3) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0P9_6pWqW10